# Stack Table-styled Divs by Column

Tags: html, css

I would like to have divs that are `display: inline-table` / `display: table-row` to line up nicely on larger screens, and stack with their content on smaller screens, achieved purely with CSS. Below is what I've tried and an explanation.

Or, visually:

*Large Screens*

```
|---------|---------|---------|
|         |         |Longer   |
|Header 1 |Header 2 |Header   |
|---------|---------|---------|
|Content  |Content2 |Content3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
```

*Smaller Screens (lt 750px wide)*

```
|-------------|
|Header 1     |
|-------------|
|Content      |
|-------------|
|Header 2     |
|-------------|
|Content2     |
|-------------|
|Longer Header|
|-------------|
|Content3     |
|-------------|
```

**The Basics**

For a page, I have a 3 column layout, where each column has a title, and content. The ideal setup is for the titles to all line up vertically (essentially `verical-align: bottom`). However, on 'mobile', which I have defined as screen width less than 750px, the title should stack above the content it would normally map to in the columns.

**Try 1**

This is how I first set it up, basically:

*HTML*

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">...</div>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </div>

    ... (and repeat) ...
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#Wrapper{
    display: inline-table;
}

#Wrapper .Column{
    display: table-row;
    width: 33%;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the `.Header` object, no matter how styled, would not line up with the other `.Header`s if it had more than one row of text in it.

**Try 2**

For this, I just separated all the header divs out into their own div, and the contents into their own wrapper, where the header wrapping div was above the content one, then styled all the headers with `display: inline-table` so that I could apply `vertical-align: bottom` to each of them. This worked for longer titles, but obviously didn't collapse in the order desired for smaller screens.

**Note**

I'd prefer a CSS only solution, but jQuery/Javascript is fine too, if there is no way around it (or the way using CSS is very bad practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`. It has a lot less bugs than `float`. Just set `font-size: 0` on the parent and `font-size: initial` on the children to removing spacing between then elements, then set the width to one third of the width of its parent.

Then use a media query to change the width to 100% if the screen is smaller than 750px.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#Wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
}

#Wrapper .Column {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 33.333333%;
}

#Wrapper .Column > * {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    #Wrapper .Column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">...</div>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">...</div>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">...</div>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `<div>`'s that act like a table, it is a lot more flexible when styling
Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ueeL0m6j/3/

```
    <div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="Content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="Content">Content</div>
    </div>
   <div class="Column">
        <div class="Header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="Content">Content</div>
    </div>

   </div>`
```

css

```
.Wrapper{width: 100%;}
.Column{width: 32%; float: left; text-align: center;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px){

    .Column{width: 32%;margin-right: 67%;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd prefer to use `inline-block` if I can (as Tiny Giant showed an example of), just given the context of this content in my project.

Comment: You should be more specific when asking a question then.